# Controlling the "Open in ..." button in the Quick Look (preview) panel

Tags: macos, cocoa

The `QLPreviewPanel` window has a button that will allow the user to open the quick look document they are currently previewing by launching its original application.

Is it possible to (a) disable this button for some documents and (b) learn if the user has clicked that button.

My problem is that some of the `QLPreviewItem` objects I'm passing to `QLPreviewPanel` are actually placeholders that aren't intended to be opened, while others are temporary documents that get created spontaneously.

In the later case, I normally delete these when the preview is done, but obviously I don't want to do this if the user has opened them in an application.

I've looked at the API for `QLPreviewItem`, `QLPreviewPanel`, and `QLPreviewPanelDelegate` and don't see any notifications or messages that occur when the user opens an item.

If there's no API, I might just try to hack the UI by searching the `QLPreviewPanel` for an `NSButton` and hooking its action, but I don't like hacks and I'm sure this would be a fragile one.